# Better way to store matrix values for later access

Tags: java, data-structures, matrix, static

I am developing a medical app, for some certain fields in a formular I have to calculate the optimal result based on the age and height of the person. The optimal values are given in a matrix where indexes are height and age (obviously), something like this:

```
    Height 135 140 and so on...
Age     
5          1.5 1.6
10         1.6 1.8
15         1.7 1.8
and so on...
```

I can't store the values on the DB, so I was wondering what was the more efficient way to store this values.

What first came to my mind was to use this:

```
private static Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Float>> optimalValues = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Float>>();
```

being the first index the age and the second the height.

The validation of data is made through a static class, and the matrix would be built in a static initialization piece of code.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: it depends on what you will do with that data and how big it is. Can you use a 2D array? Float[][]?. Then you could add some other private and static methods to calculate the array index based on the age,height input

Comment: It will be a 16x13 matrix, I only have to check the value for that person when I validate the formular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

The main issue is whether your data will follow a strict structure or not.

- Strict: height is between 140 and 200, split by 5 unit intervals.
- Lax: you may need to enter a height of 136.

If it is strict simply a `float[][]` is ok for you as long as you adhere to the rules.
If it is lax, you need a `map` for the flexibility.

A strict structure also means, making changes to your data will be more difficult.
The map would allow you to enter any data you want without restrictions but has cons.

**Longer Answer:**
This really depends on what requirements you have.

- Will your table be exactly a 2D table with values for every cell?
- Is it going to be a sparse or jagged array?

If all your rows have exactly the same number of cells, and you don't plan on making any major changes, a simple float[][] 2D array is more efficient in all respects:

- it is faster to go through the data
- it uses slightly less memory
- you don't need to use objects, references, and boxing/unboxing
- the allocation of memory is continuous.

If on the other hand, you may suddenly decide that you want to add a hight for 136, Maps are a better fit because you can dynamically enter any new data you want.

Comment: Well the 2D array won't ever change... so I guess the float[][] is better.